# stanford nlp coreference resolution error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File doesn't exist: example_file.txt

Tags: java, ubuntu, stanford-nlp

I downloaded stanfordCoreNLP module version `stanford-corenlp-full-2018-02-27` from the download page and unzipped the file. created a example_file.txt file in the directory where it was extracted. I added the text `My name is Sam. I want to be an astronaut. I had snacks a while ago.`. I navigated to the folder it was extracted to and tried to run the example code given for co-reference resolution in the command line

[stanfordNLP page](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/coref.html)

```
java -Xmx5g -cp stanford-corenlp-3.9.1.jar:stanford-corenlp-3.9.1-sources.jar:* edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,parse,mention,coref -coref.algorithm neural -file example_file.txt
```

I am getting below error message

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File doesn't exist: example_file.txt
    at edu.stanford.nlp.io.FileSequentialCollection$FileSequentialCollectionIterator.primeNextFile(FileSequentialCollection.java:364)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.io.FileSequentialCollection$FileSequentialCollectionIterator.<init>(FileSequentialCollection.java:269)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.io.FileSequentialCollection.iterator(FileSequentialCollection.java:238)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.processFiles(StanfordCoreNLP.java:1166)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.processFiles(StanfordCoreNLP.java:1010)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.run(StanfordCoreNLP.java:1365)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.main(StanfordCoreNLP.java:1427)
```

Any help on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java lookup resources within the classpath that you defined with `-cp` option. The directory that contains `example_file.txt` should probably be included in it

`-cp ".:stanford-corenlp-3.9.1.jar:stanford-corenlp-3.9.1-sources.jar:*"`

The dot added to the class path means `this directory` which apparently contains your file. Also, double quotes prevent the shell to expand the wildcard at the end that it should not be there in my opinion unless it contains jars relevant to the app. At most, it could be `*.jar`.

Comment: how can i add a file from a different location and save the output in another location?

Comment: It depends how the app works. Try adding it with its absolute path `/home/me/app/file.txt`.

Comment: and for output?

Comment: The link you provided mentions `-coref.conllOutputPath <where-to-save-system-output>` but again, depends on that app. Console output can be be saved to file with this pipe `java ... 2>&1 | tee /path/to/app.log` or `java... 2>&1 > /path/to/app.log`

Comment: Thanks for your help!!